# PHP / RegEx - Group 1 to Full Match, Get everything between hash and space

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to find the correct regex to get everything between the '#' and ' ' (Space) from the following string...

*Subscription#sub_be0e1de5bc859170ebbe 9,99€ pro Tag*

... I need only 'sub_be0e1de5bc859170ebbe'.

With the following PHP code/regex I receive the correct result, but I want the result as full match and not as group 1.

```
preg_match('/#(.*?)[[:space:]]/', $transactionResponse->getDescription(), $output);
echo $output['1'];
```

How the regex should be to receive the full match regular expression 'sub_be0e1de5bc859170ebbe' and not '#sub_be0e1de5bc859170ebbe '.

Thanks for assistance!

Comment: why do you not want to use group 1?

Comment: Otherwise I receive the result '#sub_ee22d2ad253c08c03a4d '. I want the result without hash and space at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
preg_match('/#\K[^[:space:]]+/', $transactionResponse->getDescription(), $output);
```

Match `#` and omit it with `\K` *match reset* operator, then match 1+ chars other than whitespace. The `[^[:space:]]` can be replaced with `\S` (any non-whitespace char).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OqgE0n/1).