# Regex - matching 4 digits number after certain word as full match not a group

Tags: php, regex, extract

I'm having hard time trying to figure out regular expression that will extract 4 digits long number after certain word as full match.

Here is the text:

```
FV 7017 FOR SOMETHING 1076,33 USD.
```

and here is my regular expression to extract the 4 digits number:

```
/FV (\d{4,})/
```

That will result in:

```
Full match  = `FV 7017`
Group 1 match = `7017`
```

Is it possible to exclude that "FV" word using regex to have that result as full match?

Comment: You could explode on space and take part two of the exploded array

Comment: Why not just access `$matches[1]`? What is the problem with that here? Your solution works as is, no need to complicate things with lookarounds.

Comment: preg_match always gives the full string that matches the pattern in `$matches[0]`. Unless you want to `shift($matches);`, it will always be in position 0.

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44191209/php-regex-group-1-to-full-match-get-everything-between-hash-and-space/44191277#44191277

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4 steps faster than a positive lookbehind, is to use `\K` to restart the fullstring match.

```
/FV \K\d{4}/
```

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hCVXXm/1)

PHP Implementation:

```
$string='FV 7017 FOR SOMETHING 1076,33 USD.';
echo preg_match('/FV \K\d{4}/',$string,$out)?$out[0]:'fail';
// output: 7017
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible in PHP: just use so-called positive lookbehind [assertion](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php) ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y8nFai/1))

```
/(?<=FV )\d{4,}/
```

It reads as "match four or more digits, but only if they're preceded by `'FV '` sequence".